# can we disable language selections in Azure Databricks and just have one or couple options and default language at cluster level?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I want to create Azure databricks environment where it defaults notebooks to SQL for all users and say users will have only SQL & Python option to choose from.

didn't see any option as such to do this.
we can set default language at notebook level per user but did not find anything to force language for all users on particular cluster

Answer (score 0):

By default, [shared clusters only allow SQL & Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#access-mode), so you can create such cluster and give people permissions to use it.  Although it's not possible to enforce the language selection for notebooks, but on the shared clusters, even if people will write Scala or R code, they won't be able to execute it.